# Jquery validation on dynamically created inputs using angular ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-validate, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using jQuery validation library for validating my forms created using Angular.JS. I am able to add validations on all static/known input fields in the form.

Along with fix inputs I am going to have some dynamic questions in the form. These questions are going to get rendered using `ng-repeat` directive.

I am able to validate input only if `id` and `name` of the input control are known. In case of dynamic control we can not predict the same.

### HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="PersonController">
        <div ng-repeat="social in formData.socials">
            <ng-form name="urlForm">
                  <input type="url" name="socialUrl" ng-model="social.url">
                  <span class="alert error" ng-show="urlForm.socialUrl.$error.url">URL error</span>
            </ng-form>
        </div> 
        <hr>

        <form id="contact-form">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address">
            </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div ng-repeat="question in Questions">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">{{question.Title}}</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input name="question">
            </div>
            <br/>
          </div> 
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

I have checked the approach of validating dynamic input control using `ng-form` element. But I want to validate the form using jQuery validation only as I am going to have jQuery bootstrap popovers which works along with jQuery Validation only.

### Javascript:

```
angular.module('directive', []).controller('PersonController', function personController($scope) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.formData = {
        socials: [{
            url: 'http://www.valid.com'},
        {
            url: 'invalid url'}]
    };

    $scope.Questions = [
            { "Title": "Whats your name?", "Type": "Text" },
            { "Title": "Whats your birthdate?", "Type": "Date" }
        ];

    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#contact-form').validate({
          rules: {
              email: {
                  required: true,
                  email: true
              }
          },
          highlight: function (element) {
              $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
          },
          success: function (element) {
              element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                  .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
          }
      });

    });

});
```

Please refer this: http://plnkr.co/edit/3jiYucTKOlW4G0TISFNj?p=preview

How can I add jQuery validation rule for dynamic element? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking with this question "How can I add jQuery validation rule for dynamic element?" Give the jQuery validation rule example, and also what part of the dynamic element are you trying to access? name? id? type?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you are taking jQuery validation for angularJs. Angular have a built in support for form validation and that gives you more flexibility in your development. Please refer the documentation ( https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms )

Comment: As I said in the question I am going to use jQuery bootstrap popover. This fits with jQuery validation